# OWIN authentication in MVC 5: Not able to use between two web sites in a same domain

Tags: single-sign-on, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, owin

I am trying to implement authentication using OWIN.
(MVC 5 + Entity 6 (code first)+ OWIN)

Scenario is:
1.  Company will have a portal which will be the entry point to many small web based tools.

2. The portal will have a login screen, which will be used to authenticate a user. OWIN is expected to be used (code first Entity 6)

3. Once the user logs on to the portal, custom claim is added to the user claim information (having some information)

4. When user clicks on the any tool, it should NOT ask for the user to login as it has been already logged in.

Point to be considered is : Portal and tools will be part of SAME domain.

But, somehow, I am not able to understand, how my tool is going to read/get information from the Portal that the user is authenticated and retrieve the claims.

Can somebody help me out ?